# Installing treads and risers to existing stair runs

Tags: wood

I wish to replace existing treads and risers on stair runs that were built by a
builder who believed in cutting corners any way he could.  There are stringers.  The treads and risers consist of 6" veneered plywood on each side of the step butting against the stringers.  The space between the plywood sections was left open for carpet, which presently exists.  Before I begin I need to know the best way to remove the plywood sections so that I may install solid oak treads and risers.

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Answer (score 1):

The stair treads are set to a base material, if you are lucky it is not glued down. Just pull them off and removed the nails or screws that are left over.

You will most likely need to do something with the base material as well. The thickness of the new material most likely will be thicker than the cap material you remove, making the first tread from the lower level as much as 1/2" different than the rest, creating a trip hazard. This will occur at the top too.

Code allows a difference of 3/8" total from the largest to the smallest tread.

A picture would really help detail the answer better...